# Semantic-ui accordion get index of opened item inside onOpen event

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, semantic-ui

I have a semantic-ui accordion. It is working properly. But when user reloads page it is opening the default index item as expected. What I want is to open the lastly active index after page refresh. I decide to use javascript `document.cookie` to keep last active item's index. My problem is that I cannot get the index of element inside `onOpen` event.

HTML :

```
 <div class="ui styled accordion sticky">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="title active">
            Users
        </div>
        <div class="content active">
            List
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="title active">
            Items
        </div>
        <div class="content active">
            List
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQ:

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion({
    onOpen: function (item) {
         setCookie('acordionIndex',this.index);
    }
}).accordion('open', getCookie('acordionIndex'));
```

I found this question [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573315/determine-currently-opened-semantic-ui-accordion-index) but the advised solution is not working.

Note : my `getCookie` and `setCookie` functions are working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved by trying alternative options. Changed `onOpen` event to `onOpening`

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion('open', getCookie('acordionIndex') * 1).accordion({
        onOpening: function (item) {
            setCookie('acordionIndex', this.index('.content') - 1, 2)
        }
});
```